Configure nginx to use proxy server for all outboud requests
I want to configure nginx in such a way that all requests to destination api url (eg: https://www.example.com/endpoint) from source server goes through proxy server (http://proxyserverip:proxyserverport)
when i do curl and wget commands to the url (https://www.example.com/endpoint) it gives me proper response by connecting to proxy server  but nginx gives me error like host not found in upstream
i dont want to set anything in /etc/hosts file also as it resolves domain to ip, the destination api url domain should be resolved using proxy server
I'm using redhat server, http_proxy and https_proxy is set in etc/profile also
